# Migrating PHP/MySQL web application to use Google Cloud SQL

Tags: php, sql, cloud

I have a beginner's question which might have been answered earlier but I am sure technology has changed. 
I have a PHP/MySQL based web application running on a hosted environment and I want to migrate it to Google cloud SQL. 
Over the period, it has built into a good enough relational database schema and historic data. 
The question is is it possible to use this existing data schema and 
the data by uploading it on google cloud sql environment? If yes then how 
and a sample would be appreciated.

will there be any extensive change to the existing php and mysql code?

Regards, 
Jack

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that Google Cloud SQL doesn't actually support PHP scripts! I'm in a similar position to you, currently we're running on a MySQL/PHP server, I've explored various options such as Google, Parse, StackMob etc and ultimately decided against it for a few reasons.

If I were to start making a new product again, I'd definitely look into cloud storage in a lot more depth, it would have saved a lot of headache setting up my own backend and making sure it was robust, secure etc. However, now that I have made my own back-end that runs very well and has been properly 'field tested', I'm reluctant to just move to the cloud for the sake of it.

The cloud is the new technology everyone is heading to, and I agree it probably is the right direction, but the advantages it offers (imo) aren't so great for most existing products, especially ones with complex logic. PHP/MySQL can stil do its job very well in the right hands.

Thats just my thoughts anyway - I've tried and failed to find a trustworthy cloud provider that supports PHP (mainly seems to be JS/Python) as this would make it a lot more attractive to me.

If it's scalability you're after, you can rent Cloud server space (even as a VPS) from 'traditional' hosting companies. You run them in much the same way through cPanel, PHPMyAdmin etc, but behind the scenes they are distributed across a worldwide network rather than just residing on one machine, giving them many of the advantages of cloud solutions such as better handling of traffic surges, scalability etc.

I am NOT an expert in all this by any means, just talking by my own experience from researching this the last few weeks. You may get a better answer from soneone else!